# How to use a variable from a class in another class

Tags: python

So for this case, I have a list of strings in a class called A. Within this class, it updates any element in the list. For example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self._list = ['BBB']

    def change(self):
        self._grid[0][2] = '*'
```

Then, I need to use a class called B to print out the string as such:

```
class B: 
    def print(self):
        pass
     # with this function, I need to print 'BBB'
     # from the list in class A. I can hardcode it,
     # but if and when 'BBB' gets updated, so does the 
     # 'BBB' within this class.
```

From t

Comment: Can you give a complete example of what you're trying to achieve? What does class B look like and what are you trying to do with it? Also, your indentation seems incorrect as I assume `change` should be a method on class `A`.

Comment: You can use `variable._list` where `variable` contains an `A` object.

Comment: What is `self._grid`? Is that supposed to be `self._list`?

Comment: Strings are immutable, you can't assign to an index of a string. And if you could, assigning to `[2]` would create `BB*`, not `B*B`.

Comment: You could use the return function to return the variable from B to a new variable in A.

Answer (score 0):

Just access the attribute of an A variable.

```
class B:
    
    def foo(self):
        a = A(10)
        a.change()
        print(a._list[0])
```

However, the Python convention is that a leading underscore is used as hint that the attribute is intended only for internal use in the class. The class should usually provide a method to retrieve the value if this is desired; this might be done using the `@property` decorator (typically the `_list` attribute corresponds to the `list` property).